# Can this be solved this without sin and cos?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

My daughter got this homework problem, and I can't seem to solve it. What makes it stranger is they haven't done geometry yet: like no sin and cos stuff. They did do area of triangles, but it seems like this is too advanced.  I am wondering if maybe I am missing some simple trick or something like that.

Here is the diagram:

[image: Picture]

The instruction are to calculate s1-s2.

Any ideas?  I know if you assume they are right angles you can use cos and sin, but I feel like something simpler should be involved.

Comment: By the way, I guess I don't have enough rep to embed the picture.  Hopefully, someone can edit it.

Comment: @AnotherUser Thank you.

Comment: No trig is required here. Has your daughter seen **similar triangles** yet?

Comment: Similar triangles seems promising. They are more at that basic shapes level of geometry.

Comment: If she has not learned about this notion, [Thales's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) will suffice.

Comment: Hint: $S_1 - S_2 = (S_1 + T) - (S_2+T)$ where $T$ is the area of trapezoid...

Comment: @achillehui brilliant! Please edit it as an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously it is all about similar triangles.

You have 3 triangles similar here. S₁, S₂, and the big one of area (6+8)×10/2 = 70 cm².

S₁ dimension is obviously 8/14 × the one of the big one.
So its area is (8/14)² = (4/7)² = 16/49 the area of the big one.

S₂ dimension is (6/8) = 3/4 the dimension of S₁. So its area is 9/16 the area of S₁. So 16/49×9/16 = 9/46 the area of the big one.

So S₁-S₂ area is (16-9)/49 = 1/7 times the area of the big one.

So answer is 1/7×70 = 10 cm².

Comment: Thanks, I followed that.  So the ratio of length to area is constant in similar triangles.

Comment: In similar triangles (similar anything geometrical, in reality), ratio of area is the square of ratio of length. So, here, lengths if triangle S₂ is 3/4 of matching lengths of triangle S₁. So, area of triangle S₂ is $(\frac{3}{4})^2 = \frac{9}{16}$ the area of triangle S₁. Lengths of triangle S₁ is $\frac{8}{6+8}=\frac{4}{7}$ the matching lengths of the big and similar triangle (sides 10 cm, 14 cm, area 70 cm²). So area of triangle S₁ is $(\frac{4}{7})^2 = \frac{16}{49}$ area of big triangle. Etc.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your answer and make it more readable

Answer (score 15):

Comment expanded to answer per request.

Let $T$ be the area of trapezoid under the shaded area $S_1$. Notice

$$S_1 - S_2 = (S_1 + T) - (S_2 + T)$$

and $S_1 + T$ is the area of a right triangle with height $(8+6)$cm and base $10$cm while $S_2 + T$ is the area of a rectangle with width $10$cm and height $6$cm. We have

$$S_1 - S_2 = \frac12(8+6)(10)  - (10)(6)
= 70 - 60 = 10{\rm cm}^2$$

Comment: Yep, that is even simpler than similar triangles.

Answer (score 7):

While this is probably not the way the problem was intended to be solved, we can do it with almost no calculation.

The area you are trying to compute is the area of the yellow trapezoid in the figure below, which is what is left of the $S_1$ triangle after we cut a copy of the $S_2$ triangle from the upper right corner.

[image]

By similar triangles, the original $S_2$ plus the blue trapezoid have the same total area as the copy of $S_2$ plus the yellow trapezoid,
so the blue and yellow trapezoids have equal areas.

But the two trapezoids together fill a rectangle $2\,\mathrm{cm}$ high and $10\,\mathrm{cm}$ wide, with an area of $20\,\mathrm{cm}^2.$
Since the trapezoids are equal, each has half the area of the rectangle,
that is, $10\,\mathrm{cm}^2.$

Answer (score 2):

HINT 1: $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ are similar triangles, so they will have the same ratios for their side each side lengths.

---

HINT 2: Let $x$ be the width of $S_{1}$. Then $10-x$ is the width of $S_{2}$. Create a ratio (since $S_{1}$ is similar to $S_{1}$) using $x$, $10-x$, $8$, and $6$.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is really based off of @chrslg's answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4637428/1149060

I understand it like this.  All the triangles are similar so the ratio of length to area is constant.

The area of the big triangle is 70.  The length of the triangle is 14.

The s1 triangle has a length of 8.  That is 8/14 the length of the large triangle. Since the ratio of length to area is constant, it will be be 8/14 of the area of the large triangle or (8/14) * 70 = 40.

Same idea for the s2 triangle (6/14)*70 = 30

Therefore, the different is 40 - 30 = 10.  (10 cm2)

Comment: Warning: ratio of area to length is not constant among similar rectangle. That ratio is proportional to the length. The fact that you end up on the same answer is a coincidence. In reality, (see my answer, and also my answer to your comment below it), area of $S_1$ is 1120/49 ≈ 22.85 cm², and area of $S_2$ is 630/49 ≈ 12.85 cm². So same final difference, but not the same result. Another way to compute that is Thales: horizontal side of triangle $S_1$ is 8/14×10 ≈ 5.71 cm. Horizontal side of triangle $S_2$ is 6/14×10 ≈ 4.28 cm. So areas are 5.71×8/2 = 22.84 cm ca. and 4.28*6/2=12.84 cm ca.

Comment: So, again ratio of areas are not the same as ratio of length. Ratio of area to length is not constant. What you could say is ratio of area to length squared is constant. Or ratio of square root of area to length is constant.

Comment: Seems like since the ratio of width to length is the same, and ratio of length to area will be the same, also.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_3$ be the trapezoid's area. The area of the big triangle is $S= \frac{(14)(10)}{2} = 70 \text{cm}^2$. The area of the rectangle is $R=(6)(10) = 60 \text{cm}^2$. From the figure, we have two equations
$$
\begin{align}
S_1 + S_3 &= 70,\\
S_2 + S_3 &= 60.
\end{align}
$$
It is easy now to find $S_1-S_2$.

Comment: This is more or less a duplicate of achille hui's previous answer.

Comment: @AnneBauval I agree, but I think it would be much more effective to show the equations explicitly from a pedagogical perspective.